# default(T) versus Activator.CreateInstance(T)

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to know if the below statements ever return a different result for reference types, or are they identical?

1. [`default(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)
2. [`Activator.CreateInstance(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx)

If they are identical, could you always use default(T), in this example, if the aim was to output the default value of T?:

```
if (typeof(T).IsValueType || typeof(T) == typeof(String))
{
     return default(T);
}
else
{
     return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

[Best way to test if a generic type is a string? (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498/best-way-to-test-if-a-generic-type-is-a-string-c)

ta!

Comment: No, default(T) for a reference type returns null, CreateInstance() doesn't since it creates an object of type T.  Hard to guess what this code really tries to do.

Comment: Isn't `default(string)` null too?

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the confusion! The code sample was part of the confusion, i saw it at the stackoverflow post linked below it..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are entirely different.

1. `default(T)`, when `T` is a reference type, will always be `null`.
2. `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` will create a new instance of that type using the default constructor if present, otherwise, throws `MissingMethodException`.

Answer (score 6):

For reference types, `default(T)` will be null, whereas the `CreateInstance` actually returns a new object of type T (or fails if there is no suitable constructor), so the result will never be identical.

Answer (score 3):

They will always return a different result when `T` is a reference type.  `default(T)` will return `null`, while `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` will return a new instance of `T`, created using `T`'s public parameterless constructor.

Comment: Or throw an exception if it can't find such a constructor.

Comment: Of course.  That's an exceptional case where it won't actually return anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

`default(T)` will return `null` for reference types. `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` will not. A `string` is a reference type in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whate you are asking but they are different:

`default(T)` returns `null` if `T` isn't a value type... the `CreateInstance` call creates an instance and calls the default constructor if there is one (otherwise an exception is thrown)...